# How to list open programs in taskbar with command line?

Tags: windows

In windows, how to get a list of all the apps that are currently open in the taskbar?
Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to get it. Supposedly the taskbar shows running programs with non-empty (window) title. For instance, compare

powershell (only apps with open window in taskbar):

```
gps | ? {$_.mainwindowtitle} | select name, id, mainwindowtitle | ft -AutoSize
```

and command line (apps in taskbar incl. notification area):

```
for /F "tokens=1-9 delims=," %a in ('tasklist /fo csv /v') do @if "%~i" neq "N/A" echo %~a, %~b, %~g, %~i
```

The last shows some instrumental (subservient) processes, e.g. `conhost.exe`…

Comment: Thanks, it did work though it took a long time to fetch the list on the first time, in some clients it took 10 seconds... any way to make it faster?